Google Custom Search Element appears over div element containing a drop-down menu
I am trying to add the Google Custom Search Element to a web page.  This is the code that I'm using:
<div class="gcse-searchbox-only" 
     data-resultsUrl="https://example.com/search-results/" 
     data-newWindow="false" 
     data-queryParameterName="q"
     id="search"></div>   

The widget itself works well, however the widget is placed below a div element containing other div elements that dynamically appear in order to present a drop-down menu.  The drop-down menu appears behind the widget.  How can I have the drop-down menu appear in front of the widget?
So far I've tried to address this by changing the z-index of the drop-down menu, and the z-index of the div element containing the widget, but it hasn't had any effect.

Z-index only works on items that have the position values absolute, relative,  fixed, or sticky. If you have anything that positions realitve, or inherit, the z-index will not work. You can read more at the link below:
[W3C Schools Z-index Property][1]
[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.php#:~:text=Note%3A%20z%2Dindex%20only%20works,of%20display%3Aflex%20elements).
